# Pythonic way of repeating a method call on different finite arguments

Tags: python, coding-style

I was staring at a piece of Python code I produced, which, though correct, is ugly. Is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

```
    r = self.get_pixel(x,y, RED)
    g = self.get_pixel(x,y, GREEN)
    b = self.get_pixel(x,y, BLUE)
    t = function(r,g,b)
    if t: 
        r2, g2, b2 = t  
        self.set_pixel(x,y,RED, r2)
        self.set_pixel(x,y,GREEN, g2)
        self.set_pixel(x,y,BLUE, b2)
```

The problem is the repetition of the method calls for `get_pixel` and `set_pixel`. For your information:

```
    RED, GREEN, BLUE = range(3)
```

Also note that I'd like to preserve code clarity and cleanness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To call a function with different arguments and collect the results you can use a list comprehension:

```
r1, r2, r3 = [foo(x) for x in [x1, x2, x3]]
```

To call a function for its *side-effects* I'd recommend not using a list comprehension and instead using an ordinary for loop:

```
ijs = [(i1, j1), (i2, j2), (i3, j3)]
for i, j in ijs:
    bar(i, j)
```

However your problem really is not that you *should not be calling your set pixel for each color separately*. If at all possible, change your API so that you can do this as suggested by **John Machin**:

```
old_colors = self.get_pixel_colors(x, y)
new_colors = function(*old_colors)
if new_colors:
    self.set_pixel_colors(x, y, *new_colors)
```

Comment: -1 This is merely adding ugly workarounds to an ugly API. It's API redesign time -- see the answer by @Muhammad Alkarouri, or mine.

Comment: @John Machin: Sorry I should have mentioned that. My plan was to first give a specific answer to the exact question and then to handle the bigger picture and explain the alternative approaches. But while I was typing the first part others already beat me to the second part. I didn't just want to duplicate the exact same information that others already had posted in my post so I just left it as it was as no-one else answered the question. Now I see my answer was accepted and I can't delete my answer. So I have included your answer into my post. Is that OK? Or what do you suggest I should do?

Comment: I would say by the pattern of votes that your referral to the other answer is working or not needed, so I don't think you should worry about it now. And thanks for mentioning me as "others who beat me":)

Comment: @Muhammad Alkarouri: I think the lesson I have learned is to complete my answer even if other people have already written the same thing as I was going to say.

Answer (score 5):

As you are using `self`, it appears that `get_pixel` etc are methods of *your* class. Instead of list comprehensions and `zip()` and other workarounds, look at the APIs and fix them. Two suggestions:

1. Write another method `get_pixel_colors(x, y)` which returns a 3-tuple. Then you can write `r, g, b = self.get_pixel_colors(x, y)`
2. Similarly: `self.set_pixel_colors(x, y, r, g, b)`

Even better, you can use the `*args` notation:

```
old_colors = self.get_pixel_colors(x, y)
new_colors = function(*old_colors)
if new_colors:
    self.set_pixel_colors(x, y, *new_colors)
```

Answer (score 4):

I would use a named tuple to represent the color, and change the class to use color attributes rather than individual `get_pixel(x,y,c)`.
For example:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Color = namedtuple('Color', 'red green blue')
#...

color = self.get_pixel(x, y)
t = function(*color)
if t:
    self.set_pixel(x, y, color)
```

**Edit**: thanks to John Machin for the corrections suggested here. His answer also gives more insight into the reasons for this approach. I would add that a `namedtuple` gives the advantage of having fields such as `color.red`, `color.green`, `color.blue` which I like to have available. YMMV.

Comment: This requires either changing the args of `function` (which may not be 'owned' by the OP), or writing `t = function(*color)`.

Comment: @John Machin: quite right. I forgot the `*`, which is the reason I used a tuple in the first place. I have just edited the answer to correct it.

Comment: and the last line should be `self.set_pixel(x, y, color)`

Comment: @John: serves me right for writing code without testing. I have corrected it again.

Answer (score 1):

```
colors = (RED, GREEN, BLUE)

r, g, b = [self.get_pixel(x, y, col) for col in colors]
t = function(r, g, b)
for col, rgb in zip(colors, t):
    self.set_pixel(x, y, col, rgb)
```